# How to RTL OutlinedBox hint and text on Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, android-textinputedittext

How to change OutlinedBox hint and text RTL (support Persian and Arabic):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumberLayout"
    style="@style/textInputOutlinedLayoutTheme"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumberEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="-0123456789۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰"
    android:hint="شماره تلفن همراه"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:inputType="phone" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint : as a best practice, you should set **android:hint** in the **TextInputLayout** instead of on the **TextInputEditText**.

Text : for text RTL you can use **android:textAlignment="textEnd"**.